# Assign values to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to take a value, divide it by 10 and assign those values to an array.
How do I assign the values within the for loop back to array1?

```
var value = 300000;
var array1= new Array(11);

var yaxispoints = value / 10;

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
  console.log(i * yaxispoints ); 

}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: `array1[i] = i * yaxispoints`

Comment: Use `array1.push()` to add an element to an array.

Comment: Why don't you just assign it? JosiahRuddell's comment will work.

Comment: thanks @JosiahRuddell that worked. Sorry for being vague. Pretty new this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are initializing an array you could use the [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) syntax.

This would allow you to declare and initialize your array on the same line.

```js
const value = 300000;
const yaxispoints = value / 10;

const array1= Array.from({length: 11}, (v,i) => i * yaxispoints);

array1.forEach(v => console.log(v));
```